# Serializing hashtable in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

[I have looked around and haven't found a direct answer to what I am looking for....guess it should be pretty simple.]

What is an easy way to convert a hashTable to XML and back in VB.NET? (I am using the XML format to store it into DB)

Thanks.

---

EDIT: For the details of what is in the hashTable -

Giving the exact details would mean going into the details of the whole project. So for brevity consider the following example

```
dim ht as hashtable
ht.Add(attribute1,Value1)
ht.Add(attribute2,Value2)
ht.Add(attribute3,Value3)
```

I would like to convert it into XML, something like

```
<attribute1>
  <Value1>
<\attribute1>
<attribute2>
  <Value2>
<\attribute2>
<attribute3>
  <Value3>
<\attribute3>
```

I will use this XML string to store it into a DB-Table and use it later

Comment: What's in your hashtable? What is your code?

Comment: @donA Please check the edit above

Comment: Serializing a class object or `List(Of thatClassObject)` would be a better fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot serialize any object that implements the Idictionary interface.

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class MyFakeHashtable
   'properties for your key and value
End Class
```

[Serialization - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx)